# Adding some elements broke Form keypress event

Tags: c#, forms, keypress, keyboard-events

I wrote simple app that minimize to tray if Escape is pressed (use Form keypress event for this).
Also that app have label element for debug purpose. All work normal.

But when i try add some new element (like button or radio button) my keypress event did not start. Also if I add new label keypress still working.

I investigate that button keypress event start instead Form keypress event (Because it in permanent focused?). How to fix it property?

Comment: You may need to ensure `KeyPreview` is enabled so that the form will check the keypress before any child controls.

Answer (score 3):

In the form properties, you will see the following:

[image]

Ensure that `KeyPreview` is set to `True` to allow the form itself to check the `KeyPress` event before the child controls.

Comment: Thanks @dub stylee. I was searching for same question and found your answer it works.